# How to redirect to a particular ViewController on Notification Click?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I want to redirect to particular screen once user tap the push notification. and for that i have tried below code and the view presented successfully but i'm unable to use the app navigation flow after setting the particular view as RootViewController.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    //let alertMsg = (userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary)["alert"] as! NSDictionary
    //let payload = userInfo["sendbird"] as! NSDictionary

    //APS DATA
    if let apsData = userInfo["aps"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
        print(apsData)
    }

    //USER DATA
    if let userData = userInfo["user_details"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
        print(userData)
    }

    //NOTIFICATION DATA
    if let notificationData = userInfo["notification_details"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
        print(notificationData)

        let nNotificationType   = notificationData["notification_type"] as! Int
        let nNotificationID     = notificationData["notification_id"] as! Int
    }


    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Group", bundle:nil)

    if Device.IS_IPHONE_X {
        let controller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GroupInfoViewController_iPhoneX") as! GroupInfoViewController
                let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: controller)
    }
    else {
        let controller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GroupInfoViewController_iPhone8") as! GroupInfoViewController
                let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: controller)
    }

    // Your custom way to parse data
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

Please guide me how can i use the normal app navigation after move to particular ViewController on notification tap. same like android app.

Please guide me

Comment: You can push that specific view controller from your root view controller in viewDidload/ viewDidAppear.

Comment: @mumu, you mean to say i write the code in my initial controller to push to particular controller?

Comment: Yes I meant that. @kuldeep

Comment: @mumu, let me try this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some R&D, i found the working solution to move to particular controller on notification tap over **PRESENTED** or **PUSHED** `ViewController`.

Here is the working code.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { // change your delay here

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Group", bundle: nil)

        if Device.IS_IPHONE_X {
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GroupInfoViewController_iPhoneX") as! GroupInfoViewController
            vc.nNotificationID = notificationID
            if let topVC = UIApplication.getTopViewController() {
                topVC.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
            }
        }
        else {
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GroupInfoViewController_iPhone8") as! GroupInfoViewController
            vc.nNotificationID = notificationID
            if let topVC = UIApplication.getTopViewController() {
                topVC.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

**Extension**

```
public extension UIApplication {
    class func getTopViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return getTopViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)

        } else if let tab = base as? UITabBarController, let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return getTopViewController(base: selected)

        } else if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return getTopViewController(base: presented)
        }
        return base
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a function like this:

```
func handleNotification(userInfo: [String:Any]) {

         DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            if let mainNav = AppDelegate.shared.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourVC") as! YourVC

            mainNav.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)

        }
}
}
```

You can also pass information in `userInfo`  If you want to perform certain operations or just removed that parameter.

And call this function in your this method

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    print("APNs received with: \(userInfo)")
    self.handleNotification(userInfo: userInfo as! [String : Any])


}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error : Type 'DispatchQueue' has no member 'delay'

Comment: @Kuldeep...Oh sorry this is the extension  created you can use normal `DispatchQueue ` method it will work

Comment: it works only in those controller which were pushed but this doesn't works in those controllers which were presented. How can i do this in presented controller?

Comment: @Kuldeep...well presented controllers are not in the hierarchy you need to do something for that

Comment: will you guide me something about this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourVC") as! 
 YourVC
 mainNav.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

use push or present to pass one view controller to another